# CoreGraphice Stroke Text with Gradient

Tags: macos, core-graphics, core-animation, core-text

With the help of [CGContextSetTextDrawingMode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1454253-cgcontextsettextdrawingmode) we are able to draw bordered Text. How can we fill the border with a brush (Gradient/Picture) instead of a solid color?

Can't find this on Apple Docs.

Answer (score 1):

- by using `context.addPath(path)` , then `context.clip(to: pathFrame)`

then you can use `context.drawLinearGradient`

- in order to draw without side effects,

remember to use `context.saveGState()` and `context.restoreGState()`,

---

Here is an example for `iOS` version,

you should edit it to `MacOS` version

```
class CustomV: UIView{
     override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
       
        // Create a gradient from white to red
        let colors: [CGFloat] = [
            1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
            1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
        let baseSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), let gradient =
                CGGradient(colorSpace: baseSpace, colorComponents: colors, locations: nil, count: 2) else{ return }
        
        context.saveGState()
        let offset: CGFloat = 10
        let startPoint = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - offset, y: rect.minY)
        let endPoint = CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - offset, y: rect.maxY)
        let p = CGMutablePath()
        p.move(to: startPoint)
        p.addLine(to: endPoint)
        context.addPath(p)
        context.clip(to: CGRect(origin: startPoint, size: CGSize(width: 3, height: 800)))
        context.setLineWidth(offset)
        
        context.drawLinearGradient(gradient, start: startPoint, end: endPoint, options: [])
        context.restoreGState()

    }
}
```